# CSS: Creating trailing dots after the heading where the heading is placed on a background

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Please take a look at the attached screenshot. I'm trying to create this effect in CSS.

The trailing dots need to cover the entire width of the element (100%) and be responsive. Please note that the header is placed on a background, so the following technique did not work for me, because when I give the span a background of white, the underlying pattern is no longer visible.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh5XN/1/)

[image]

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background: red;}
h1{background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/23XVz.png) repeat-x 0 0 transparent;}
h1 span{background: #fff;}
</style>

<h1><span>SERVICE</span></h1>
```

Comment: please show your dots image

Comment: As a side note, CSS has a `border-style` property that can be set to `dashed` or `dotted`. This can be used to create a dashed or dotted line using CSS instead of an image.

Comment: @Zhihao: that's true! See **[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ng3W/2/)** in my answer.

Comment: @Barnee, I'll need the dots to automatically fill the full width of the element without me giving it a certain size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this effect using display table-cell

```
body {
    background: red;
}
h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
span {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/23XVz.png) repeat-x 0 center;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ng3W/5/)

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h1>Service<span></span></h1>
```

Css:

```
h1 span {
   display: inline-block;
   background: url(dots.gif) repeat-x 0 0 transparent
}
```

Here's two examples: **[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ng3W/)**, **[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ng3W/2/)**.

***Edit:***

Here is **[exmaple 3](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ng3W/3/)** with you dashed image.

Comment: There is no need to have a empty element here.

Comment: @Barnee, on your example 3, try resizing the window, you'll see that the dots would drop below the text. The website I'm working on is also a responsive website, I'll need the dots to stay and just fill the remaining area.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the positioning of your background image, try:

`h1{background: url(dots.gif) repeat-x center center transparent;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/bh5XN/

Comment: But if you try to add a background image or color to the body, than the `h1 span` has a white background.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, see the updated fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/bh5XN/1/

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that part.